# ES6 .filter() that will return an array of objects WITHOUT certain strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm able to successfully return an array based on if it contains a tag that equals === 'Featured'. Here is the code:

```
  getFeatured() {
    return blogPosts.filter((item) => (
      item.tags.some((value) => value === 'Featured')
    ))

  }
```

This filters each blog post, then I use .some() on the array of tags within the post.

I need to now create a function that returns an array of posts that don't contain the word "Featured".

Here is the function so far:

```
  renderRegular() {
    const regularPost = blogPosts.filter((item) => (
      item.tags.find((value) => value !== 'Featured' )
    ))

    console.log(regularPost)

  }
```

Comment: Ok, and what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead of [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), which will return `true` if all the elements satisfy the predicate. In this case, if all  the tags (every tag) are not equal to `'Featured'` or, put in a different way, if none of the tags is equal to `'Featured'` (see also @Barmar's answer):

```js
const posts = [{
  title: 'Post 1',
  tags: ['Featured'],
}, {
  title: 'Post 2',
  tags: ['Foo', 'Featured'],
}, {
  title: 'Post 3',
  tags: ['Bar'],
}];

const regularPost = posts.filter(item =>
  item.tags.every(value => value !== 'Featured'));

console.log(regularPost);
```

The advantage of this is that you can also check conditions other than equal or not equal easily:

```js
const posts = [{
  title: 'Post 1',
  tags: ['Featured'],
}, {
  title: 'Post 2',
  tags: ['Foo', 'FEATURED POSTS'],
}, {
  title: 'Post 3',
  tags: ['Bar'],
}];

const regularPost = posts.filter(item =>
  item.tags.every(value => !value.match(/featured/gi)));

console.log(regularPost);
```

But if you are only doing an equality comparison, [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) might be better options:

```js
const posts = [{
  title: 'Post 1',
  tags: ['Featured'],
}, {
  title: 'Post 2',
  tags: ['Foo', 'Featured'],
}, {
  title: 'Post 3',
  tags: ['Bar'],
}];
  
// const regularPost = posts.filter(item =>
//   item.tags.indexOf('Featured') === -1);

const regularPost = posts.filter(item =>
  !item.tags.includes('Featured'));

console.log(regularPost);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply negating the test is not the way to do this. If the tags are `Tag1, Featured, Tag2`, your test will succeed because `"Tag1" != "Featured"`.

Instead, you need to negate the result of `some()` rather than the test inside it.

```
  renderRegular() {
    return blogPosts.filter((item) => (
      !item.tags.some((value) => value === 'Featured')
    ))
  }
```

Or you can apply [de Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). The opposite of "some X == Y" is "every X != Y":

```
  renderRegular() {
    return blogPosts.filter((item) => (
      item.tags.every((value) => value !== 'Featured')
    ))
  }
```

Comment: I agree with the solution using some but I'm still in doubt using the every method. Maybe, I'm thinking odd.

Comment: Try executing it on paper, you'll see that it's correct. If every element of an array is not equal to `Featured`, that means the array doesn't contain `Featured`.

Comment: and then no post will be listed... what I'm thinking exactly is like that. It should list all other posts except Featured tag.

Comment: That's what it will do. `every()` isn't operating on the array of posts, it's operating on the array of tags for just one post at a time. If the tag array doesn't contain `Featured`, `every()` returns `true`, so `filter` returns that post.

Comment: Look at the code snippets in Danziger's answer, they show that it works.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Replace the arrow functions with normal functions and you might see what is going on easily.

Answer (score 0):

`find` will return first element that matches your condition, as it will return a element i.e. a string which will evaluate to true always. Use `indexOf` to search for presence of string.

```
renderRegular() {
    const regularPost = blogPosts.filter((item) => (
      item.tags.indexOf('Featured') === -1
    ))

    console.log(regularPost)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may assign the item:

```
renderRegular() {
    const regularPost = blogPosts.filter((item) => 
      // assign item so the filter will return item matched condition with the find
      item = item.tags.find((value) => value !== 'Featured'
    ))
}
```